# How to get an overall p-value for an independent categorical variable using generalized estimating equations (geeglm) in R

Tags: r, p-value, generalized-estimating-equations, geepack

I would like to know if there is a way to get an overall p-value for an independent categorical variable using generalized estimating equations in R. When I run the analysis, the output provides p-values for each level of the categorical variable, instead of an overall p-value for the variable itself.

One example of an output is this:

```
Call:
geeglm(formula = modality ~ factor(smoking_status), family = "binomial", 
    data = airleak_cleaned_included, id = as.factor(mrn))

 Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std.err  Wald Pr(>|W|)   
(Intercept)                0.875   0.266 10.82    0.001 **
factor(smoking_status)1   -0.359   0.338  1.13    0.287   
factor(smoking_status)2   -1.099   0.722  2.32    0.128   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation structure = independence 
Estimated Scale Parameters:

            Estimate Std.err
(Intercept)        1  0.0597
Number of clusters:   176  Maximum cluster size: 1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please state your variables, problem and objective of study. Nature of data and experiment design etc?